# DALLAS DS1220AB Non-volatile SRAM from 20 years ago --- reusable?

Tags: ram

The DALLAS DS1220ABs that I have were mostly manufactured in 1992 and 1993, I have a bunch of pulls.  The datasheet speaks of a "lithium" battery inside (not "lithium-ion").  Do people here think that applying GND and VCC would recharge the "lithium" battery inside to make these chips quite usable, or is that just not the way it works?

(for e.g.  http://cgi.ebay.com/Dallas-DS1220AB-200-16K-NonVolatile-SRAM-/170576839051)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The batteries are not rechargeable and the modules are designed to be replaced when they fail, not recharged.

I know this because the modules are quite popular in old HP digitising oscilloscopes, of which I own one. After about 20 years the battery hits minimum voltage and calibration as well as some settings get reset back to defaults. I have heard of people having success with removing the battery from the package and replacing it, although I am not sure how well this would actually work. Applying a voltage to Vcc will not serve to charge the battery: this is because there is protection circuitry built into the module such that it does not recharge the non-rechargeable cell and damage the cell in the process.

Comment: Apparently the battery isn't switched into the circuit until power is applied. So... if they're pulls from used equipment, there's a very good chance the non-volatile property will be gone. It'll still work fine as SRAM though...

Comment: It'll still work fine as SRAM!  That is good news, so maybe I won't have to throw them all away!

Answer (score 0):

Dallas also did a unit with a real time clock.

What you have is several parts in one package.

1. Lithium battery (or Cell) - Non rechargeable - Not designed to be recharged
2. SDRAM ic (or Real time Clock IC with SDRAM - External xtal)
3. Power control IC - e.g. DS1210 - this switches from external to internal battery, and disables the write control signal when external supply falls.

The RTC versions had visible terminal for the battery, which if you were careful you could remove (Damaging the Package) and replace with another cell/battery or cell/battery holder.

The one shown in your link was made in 1996 - and is now about 14 years old. - the internal battery will be dead as even if it was not used - it would be past it's shelf life. It could be used as a SDRAM but would not hold data when power is removed.